# Consolidating Dialog Box Code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've been coming up to speed on jQuery but I think I'm still missing some fundamentals.  I have a complex set of dialog popups (distilled below) and I'm lost at how to consolidate them into one 'class'.

HTML:

```
 <div id="FirstDialogFrame" 
      title="First" 
      data-button="Alert First"
      data-alert="FirstAlert">
 </div>

 <div id="SecondDialogFrame" 
      title="Second" 
      data-button="Alert First"
      data-alert="SecondAlert" >
 </div>

 <button id="PopFirst">First</button>
 <button id="SecondFirst">Second</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#FirstDialogFrame").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    height: 340,
    width: 340,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Alert": function() {
            alert($(this).attr("data-alert"));
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Close: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("#SecondDialogFrame").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    height: 340,
    width: 340,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Alert": function() {
            alert($(this).attr("data-alert"));
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Close: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("#PopFirst").click(function() {
    $("#FirstDialogFrame").dialog("open");
});

$("#SecondFirst").click(function() {
    $("#SecondDialogFrame").dialog("open");
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tzerb/BYKqM/

Any feedback appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
 <div id="FirstDialogFrame" class="popup"
      title="First" 
      data-button="Alert First"
      data-alert="FirstAlert">
 </div>

 <div id="SecondDialogFrame" class="popup"
      title="Second" 
      data-button="Alert First"
      data-alert="SecondAlert" >
 </div>

 <button id="PopFirst">First</button>
 <button id="SecondFirst">Second</button>
```

Javascript

```
 $(".popup").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    height: 340,
    width: 340,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Alert": function() {
            alert($(this).attr("data-alert"));
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Close: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("#PopFirst").click(function() {
    $("#FirstDialogFrame").dialog("open");
});

$("#SecondFirst").click(function() {
    $("#SecondDialogFrame").dialog("open");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might move the javascript into the click event.
So your page loads quicker and the dialog is built when it is needed.

```
<button class="popup" 
  data-button="Alert First" 
  title="First" 
  data-alert="FirstAlert">Open first dialog</button>

<button class="popup" title="Second" 
  data-button="Alert First"
  data-alert="SecondAlert">Open second dialog</button>
```

And your code would look like this:

```
$("button.popup").click(function(){
  $("<div/>")
     .appendTo(document.body)
     .attr('title', this.title)
     .data('button', $(this).data('button'))
     .data('alert', $(this).data('alert'))
     .dialog({
         resizable: true,
         height: 340,
         width: 340,
         modal: true,
         close: function(event, ui) {
           $(this).remove();
         },
         buttons: {
             "Alert": function() {
                 alert($(this).data('alert'));
                 $(this).dialog("close");
             },
             Close: function() {
                 $(this).dialog("close");
             }
         }
     });

});
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e6t76/

Answer (score 1):

Why not combine the dialog selectors and have different opening events since they both have the same params?

```
$("#FirstDialogFrame, #SecondDialogFrame").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    height: 340,
    width: 340,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Alert": function() {
            alert($(this).attr("data-alert"));
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Close: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("#PopFirst").click(function() {
    $("#FirstDialogFrame").dialog("open");
});

$("#SecondFirst").click(function() {
    $("#SecondDialogFrame").dialog("open");
});
```